# What is the difference between 'local value' and 'master value'?

Tags: php-ini, php

When I display `phpinfo();` I see two columns:  `local value` and `master value`. When will the web server choose `local value` and when will it choose `master value`?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

`master` is either the value compiled into PHP, or set via a main `php.ini` directive. I.e., the value that's in effect when PHP fires up, before it executes any of your code.

`local` is the value that's currently in effect at the moment you call `phpinfo()`. This local value is the *end* result of any overrides that have taken place via `ini_set()` calls, `php_value` directives in httpd.conf/.htaccess, etc.

For example,

```
php.ini:     foo=bar
httpd.conf:  php_value foo baz
.htaccess:   php_value foo qux
ini_set:     ini_set('foo', 'kittens');
.user.ini    foo=bar   # this file works conditionally see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32193087/1818723
```

Given that, the `master` value is `qux`, and the `local` value is `kittens`.

Comment: I understand this, I need to know when web-server will use master value instead of local value if the are different or it'll never happen

Comment: Based on what you wrote, wouldn't the master value be 'bar', since it's set in the php.ini file?

Comment: that gets murkey. .ini is what's in effect when the webserver child loads up php, but that can get overridden on a per-dir/per-site/per-whatever basis with the .conf and .htaccess overrides. but when line #1 of your script fires, that value is "qux", and is listed as the master.

Comment: @Aine Yes, the "master value" (as reported by `phpinfo()`) would indeed be "bar" in this example. This is as stated in the first paragraph of the answer (not sure why the apparent change in reasoning in the example?). Setting a PHP config value in `httpd.conf`, `.htaccess` or `.user.ini`, etc. does not change the reported "master value", only the "local value" is changed.

Comment: It is not clear in the answer that a .user.ini file can also change the local value. I recommend that the answer be edited to make that clear.

Comment: @MarcB : I think according to the first paragraph of the answer the last line of the answer should be "Given that, the master value is bar, and the local value is baz(if set in httpd.conf), qux(if set in .htaccess), kittens(if set using ini_set)". If I've understood the concept correctly and the last statement which I suggested is also correct, please change the last statement of the answer to the one I suggested to clear the confusion.

Comment: @MarcB : Please update your answer to clear the created confusion over the `master value` `qux`

Comment: @PHPLover - what do you mean by "local value is baz (if set in httpd.conf)", etc.? At the time phpinfo runs, *all* those locations have taken effect, so the local value is "whatever value `foo` was set to most recently [last]", which in his example is `kittens`. It doesn't matter whether foo was set to baz in httpd.conf, if anything else set foo after that.

Comment: Downvoted because I think the last sentence should be changed as mentioned.

Answer (score 16):

"Master Value" (from *php.ini*) could be overridden with "Local Value" in **httpd.conf**, **.htaccess** or other Apache configuration with the **php_value** directive.

The first is the local value, and the second is the global value. The local value overrides the global value and is set within PHP, HTACCESS, etc., whereas the global value is set within *php.ini*. To answer your question, the first value is used.

Comment: So if, for example, local value = 0, but master value = 1440 web-server will use 0 always, right?

Comment: The first is the local value, the second is the global value. The local value overrides the global value and is set within PHP, HTACCESS, etc. whereas the global value is set within php.ini. To answer your question, the first value is used; local value = 0

Answer (score 7):

The hosted website will check local values in `.htaccess` or `.user.ini` first. (These files are in your local website folder and also can say local level configuration files.)

Local values override Master values, so `php` will check the local values first.

The master value is set in `php.ini` (main PHP configuration file).
Run the following commands in the terminal to find the correct path:

```
php -i | grep 'Configuration File'
```

or

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

So even if we set master values in `php.ini`, we also need to check local values in `.htaccess` or `.user.ini`.

Here is explanation when `.htaccess` vs `.user.ini` works https://stackoverflow.com/a/32193087/1818723

Comment: What do you mean by *"also can say local level configuration files"* (seems incomprehensible)? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55550055/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

local is website-or-user wide while master is system-wide configuration option.

would be easier and quicker to understand if it's named "global" instead of master

since the hidden `.user.ini` and `.htaccess` files are site-wide they contain local values along with the `ini_set` function to set options within the `.php` file

the `PHPRC` and `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR` files would contain the master (global, system-wide) values

`PHPRC`: /etc/php.ini

`PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR`: /etc/php/*.ini