# How do you get PHP master ini values

Tags: php

In `phpinfo` it shows you the "Master" and "Local" values for ini settings.

I want to compare them to determine whether a setting has changed since the start of the script.

Getting the local values is easy:

```
<?php
$local = ini_get('setting');
```

But I can't find anything describing how to get the master value.

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520744/what-is-the-difference-between-local-value-and-master-value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that [`get_cfg_var()`](http://php.net/manual/function.get-cfg-var.php) is what you are looking for.

To quote [a comment in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-cfg-var.php#114975)

> The difference between `ini_get()` and `get_cfg_var()` is as follows:
>
> - `ini_get()`: returns the current value in .htaccess or as defined in PHP_INI_USER or PHP_INI_PERDIR
> - `get_cfg_var()`: returns the values defined in the php.ini