# Where I can find a PHP directive titled as 'PHPIniDir'?

Tags: php, apache, api, directive, httpserver

I've installed **PHP 7.2.3** on my machine running on **Windows 10** using the latest copy of **XAMPP** installer.

So, I'm running **Apache/2.4.29 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0g PHP/7.2.3**

I come across following line from the [PHP Manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php#configuration.file)

> SAPI module specific location (*PHPIniDir* directive in Apache 2, *-c*
>   command line option in CGI and CLI, *php_ini* parameter in NSAPI,
>   *PHP_INI_PATH* environment variable in THTTPD)

I checked into the output of

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

but I couldn't find out a directive named **PHPIniDir** anywhere.

Can someone please help me in finding out/locating the **PHPIniDir** directive?

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13984489/3179389

Comment: @godot : In the answer you suggested, there is no such directive titled 'PHPIniDir'

Comment: It's an Apache directive, so you most likely find it in the central server configuration or a vhost ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value you're looking for is displayed in the **Loaded Configuration File** section:

[image]

`phpinfo()` does not get into details of where or how each setting is set, beyond the [Local/Master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520744/what-is-the-difference-between-local-value-and-master-value) columns of the PHP directives themselves.

As your quote suggests, `PHPIniDir` is an Apache HTTP Server directive provided by the mod_php module (in other words, **`PHPIniDir` is not a PHP directive**) so you configure it in **Apache configuration files**:

[image: mod_php7.conf]

Comment: If such is the case then why on the PHP directive list page at https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php also there is no such directive titled 'PHPIniDir' and what are local and master values? What's the need of having two values for few directives?

Comment: You mean to say there is no such PHP directive titled 'PHPIniDir' exist! Right?

Comment: Yes, I meat that.